# Silverlight 4: Chart Toolkit Color Set

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, charts, silverlight-toolkit

Im migrating my Chart code from visifire to Toolkit. I would like to know the counter part of ColorSet property[sample value Caravan,Picasso..] of Visifire to Toolkit.

Is there any?

TIA

Comment: It isn't so obvious, because the Caravan colorset has 5 colors whereas toolkit charts require 16. The property is called `Palette`, but the migration isn't obvious. I will create an example within a hour.

Answer (score 5):

At first you need to copy color codes from a Visifire color set. They are defined in the file 
`(Visifire source code)\Common\SLVisifireCharts\ColorSets.xaml` or [here](http://visifire.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/63177#703607).

The counterpart of the `ColorSet` property is the `Palette` property, which takes complex dictionary of resources. Here is the example for the `Caravan` color set:

```
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color1" Color="#58706d" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color2" Color="#4b5757" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color3" Color="#7c8a6e" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color4" Color="#b0b087" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color5" Color="#e3e3d1" />

    <datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="CaravanPalette">
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color1}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color2}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color3}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color4}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color5}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
```

And it is applied to the chart so:

```
<chart:Chart Palette="{StaticResource CaravanPalette}">
```

Although I have applied the same colors, the toolkit chart differs a lot and has rather bright colors:
[image]

I can change the template of the column, but I'm not designer and the result is still different:

```
    <Style x:Key="columnStyle" TargetType="Control">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="chart:ColumnDataPoint">
                    <Border
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    Opacity="0"
                    x:Name="Root">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="MouseOverHighlight"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0.6"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="SelectionHighlight"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0.6"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="RevealStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Shown">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Hidden">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="Root"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="SelectionHighlight" Fill="Red" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="MouseOverHighlight" Fill="White" Opacity="0"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding FormattedDependentValue}"/>
                        </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection x:Key="CaravanPalette">
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource columnStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color1}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource columnStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color2}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource columnStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color3}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource columnStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color4}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>

        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" BasedOn="{StaticResource columnStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color5}"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </datavis:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
```

[image]

And one last remark: toolkit chart doesn't render different colors for a single series. If you have 1 item in the legend - all categories will be the same color. And this behavior can't be changed.