# Implicity style for BarDataPoint is not applied

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am currently working on creating a theme for charts.
Beside other things, I want to make the bars in BarSeries have a flat look(without borders).
I want to make it to work with implicit styling so I added a Style to BarDataPoint(without a Key because it needs to work by implicit styling) but it is not applied.

Any idea why is it is not applied? 
Is it because of DataPointStyle style from Palette which is applied instead?

What I am trying to do is to change the look of the BarDataPoint but still have the colors from the palette applied. And also try to make this work by pure XAML(if possible).

In order to make this work, the only way I see is by changing DataPointStyle(in each ResourceDictionary from Chart.Palette) to have TargetType set to BarDataPoint and Template set to my template implementation:

```
 <toolkit:Chart.Palette>
    <toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="toolkit:BarDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource BarDataPointStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="toolkit:BarDataPoint" BasedOn="{StaticResource BarDataPointStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
</toolkit:Chart.Palette>
```

But since this is for implicit style for Chart control, how would that work if I have a Char control with a different type of series, for example a Chart with ColumnSeries? I don't think the DataPointStyle will work in this case because it is targeting the BarDataPoint type(I suppose the app will crash).

Am I forced to create different Chart styles with different keys(each style having DataPointStyle changed to target different control template)?

But then, how will that work for a Chart control with several different series?

I also tried to use an implicit style for toolkit:BarDataPoint in the palette's resource dictionary like this, but without success:

```
<Setter Property="Palette">
        <Setter.Value>
            <toolkit:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Background"
                                     Color="#FFCA294D" />
                    <Style TargetType="toolkit:BarDataPoint">
                        <Setter Property="Template"
                                Value="{StaticResource BarDataPointTemplate}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource Background}" />
                    </Style>
```

I tried to look to themes like JetPack but they don't seem to do what I want.

Thanks!

Comment: It is not implicit if you put an x:Key

Comment: sorry? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: A style is implicit (it will automatically apply to any element of the TargetType) if you don't specify `x:Key=".."`

Comment: I already know that, your comment has nothing to do with my post

Comment: Then what are you trying to achieve in the first piece of XAML you provided? I think what you're really looking for is merged dictionaries but the whole thing isn't very clear.

Comment: What I am trying to do is to change the look of the BarDataPoint by implicit styling and still have the colors from the palette applied. It looks like using implicit styling is not working so I need another way.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late update.

check this solution. may help others too 
[Silverlight 4: Chart Toolkit Color Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618581/silverlight-4-chart-toolkit-color-set/5626435#5626435)