# How to set a default color to the Pie slices in WPF Pie chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I am using WPF Pie chart with Labels using the article from  [Zag studio](http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/503).This chart refreshes for new values every 1 min. It works fine, but why the color of the pie slices changes for every refresh? is there any possible way to set up default color.The pie chart which I am displaying has only two slices.

What I have tried,

```
 <customControls:LabeledPieChart>
  <customControls:LabeledPieChart.Palette>
   <dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
   <ResourceDictionary>                                               
     <Style TargetType="dvc:PieDataPoint">
     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
     </Style>
    <Style TargetType="dvc:PieDataPoint">
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
    </Style>
  </ResourceDictionary>
  </dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
 </customControls:LabeledPieChart.Palette>
 </customControls:LabeledPieChart>
```

This above snippet returns exception as

> 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent'
>   threw an exception.

any body could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved this issue myself with the help of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5618581/silverlight-4-chart-toolkit-color-set/5626435#5626435)

here is the solution

```
  <!--to set the Pie slice color-->
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color1" Color="Maroon" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="color2" Color="DarkBlue" />

  <!--Pie Palette-->
  <customControls:LabeledPieChart.Palette>
    <dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color1}"/>
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
      <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="DataPointStyle" TargetType="Control" >
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource color2}"/>
        </Style>
      </ResourceDictionary>
    </dv:ResourceDictionaryCollection>
  </customControls:LabeledPieChart.Palette>
```