# Styling Wpf Pie Chart

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

Here is my xaml for the pie chart.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="pieChart" Title="Top Products" Margin="10,10,0,0" Height="262" BorderBrush="#00000000" DataContext="{Binding}" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="True" ForceCursor="True">
        <chartingToolkit:PieSeries DependentValuePath="Value" IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSelectionEnabled="True" />

            <!-- Plot area-->
            <chartingToolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
                </Style>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

And Here is the code for filling the data

```
public void GenerateChart()
{
    List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Apple", 101));
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Banana", 201));
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Cake", 20));
    valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Others", 200));      

    pieChart.Title = "Top Products";
    pieChart.DataContext = valueList;
}
```

And the output is as follows

[image: Chart]

Now how do i change the background color of various segments of the chart. Similar to below chart.

[image]

Comment: Please help me with the same. Have a look at my [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25660079/wpf-chart-is-not-plotting-the-chart)

Comment: Ok i will provide dropbox link for source code. wait for some minutes

Comment: Complete VS solution for chart at https://www.dropbox.com/s/helas5e8qdr1xhs/WPF.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should be able to use a [Color Palette](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183459%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Take a look at the [How to set a default colour to the Pie slices in WPF Pie chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667136/how-to-set-a-default-color-to-the-pie-slices-in-wpf-pie-chart) post here on StackOverflow.

Additionally, take a look at the [Chart Appearance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489226.aspx) article on MSDN.