# WPF: Chart is not plotting the chart

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, charts

I am developing a Chart in WPF Application. But it is not showing the chart. Chart Plot area is blank whereas I can see the number of legends on the basis of number of valueList.add I do in the code.

### XAML

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                       x:Name="MyPie"
                       Margin="10"
                       Title="Total Voting Percentage"
                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <chartingToolkit:PieSeries ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                               DependentValuePath="Total Participants"
                               IndependentValuePath="Total Voted" />
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

### Code Behind

```
public partial class TotalVoting : Window
{
    int TotalParticipant;
    int TotalVoted;
    public TotalVoting()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TotalParticipant = int.Parse(da[0].ToString()); //data reaches here
        TotalVoted = int.Parse(da1[0].ToString()) / 2; //data reaches here
        ObservableCollection<Writer> Team = new ObservableCollection<Writer> 
        { 
             new Writer("Total Participants", TotalParticipant), 
             new Writer("Participants Voted", TotalVoted),
             new Writer("Total Participants", TotalParticipant), 
             new Writer("Participants Voted", TotalVoted)
        };
        MyPie.DataContext = Team;
    }
}
public class Writer
{
    public Writer() { }
    public Writer(string writerName, int numOfTypes)
    {
        Name = writerName;
        Types = numOfTypes;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Types { get; set; }
}
```

When I run the code I can see the number of legends that too with number 1,2,3 ... so with current code it shows from 1 to 4. but doesn't show any chart on my chart control. Any clue so that I can get it done.

---

EDIT : A Change has been made to the code .. but still the same result

```
public void GenerateChart()
{
  List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
  valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Apple", 101));
  valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Banana", 201));
  valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Cake", 20));
  valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Others", 200));

  pieChart.Title = "Top Products";
  pieChart.DataContext = valueList;
}
```

the number of time `valueList.Add` is added. I can the same number of legends on the chart but no chart :(

Hope Somebody can help me !!!

Comment: In WPF, we data bind to public properties, not member variables. Make your `Team` variable a public property.

Comment: @Sheridan - I have tried even that but still the same result. I think the problem is something else

Comment: Your @valueList member is *not* a public property. It is a member variable, as is your `Team` variable.

Comment: Yeah @Sheridan you are correct but have a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464752/styling-wpf-pie-chart). and this one too a [MSDN Blog on Charting Controls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/12/07/getting-started-with-the-charting-controls.aspx)

Comment: @Sheridan - `public partial class TotalVoting : Window
{
 public List<KeyValuePair<string, double>> valueList;
 int TotalParticipant;
 
 public void GenerateChart()
        {
            valueList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, double>>();
     valueList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, double>("Apple", 101));
            pieChart.DataContext = valueList;
        }
}`

Still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the link to complete source code for the chart.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/helas5e8qdr1xhs/WPF.zip?dl=0

Comment: It worked from me! But still i'm clueless why doesnt my code was working :P